# Java Object equal method and Boolean value

Tags: java, object, boolean, equals

I have the following code snippet

```
  format(Object obj) {
    if(obj.equals("false")) {
      buffer.append("No");
    } else {
      buffer.append("Yes");
    }
  }
```

When debugging, I verify that the value of obj variable is a Boolean object with the value "false", but the if clause always go to the Yes instruction. Can you help me understand why?

Comment: Are you expecting something like `Boolean.valueOf(false).equals("false")` to return true? You're comparing a `Boolean` to a `String`... Maybe you want `obj.toString().equals("false")` (or `equalsIgnoreCase`).

Comment: You're trying to compare `String` with `Boolean`. that's why you're getting  `fasle`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare Boolean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22491853/how-to-compare-boolean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `obj.equals("false")` you're trying to compare `obj`, a `Boolean`, with `"false"`, which is a `String`.

So you can try to first convert the `Boolean` to a string:

```
if(obj.toString().equals("false")){
    buffer.append("No");
} else {
    buffer.append("Yes");
}
```

Or, even better, as suggested by @Nexevis, you can compare `obj` directly to a `Boolean`:

```
if(obj.equals(false)){
    buffer.append("No");
} else {
    buffer.append("Yes");
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to just do `obj.equals(false)` and compare to a `boolean` rather than use `String` as a fake boolean?

Comment: @Nexevis oh that's even better!